# Not a managed type despite addition to @EntityScan

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a simple application in SpringBoot, but I still have an error. My files structure looks like this:

[image]

And my classes:

ModelController

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/task")
public class ModelController {
ToDoListService service;
@Autowired
ModelController (ToDoListService service){
    this.service=service;
}
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Task>> getProducts() {
        return service.getAllProducts();
    }
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Task> addProduct(@RequestBody JSONObject object) {
        return service.addProduct(object);
    }
}
```

Task

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tasks")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Task {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private final String title;
private final String description;
private final int priority;
private final String date;
}
```

ModelRepository

```
@Repository
public interface ModelRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Integer> {
}
```

ToDoListService

```
@Service
public class ToDoListService {
    private final ModelRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    ToDoListService(ModelRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
    public ResponseEntity<List<Task>> getAllProducts() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(repository.findAll());
    }
    public ResponseEntity<Task> addProduct( JSONObject object) {
        Task added = new Task(object.get("title").toString(), object.get("description").toString(), Integer.parseInt(object.get("priority").toString()), object.get("date").toString());
        repository.save(added);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(added);
    }
}
```

ProjectConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.todolist3.repositories")
@ComponentScan({ "com.example.*" })
@EntityScan({ "com.example.todolist3.models" })
public class ProjectConfig {
}
```

ToDoList3Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ToDoList3Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ToDoList3Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And my error is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'modelController' defined in file [controllers/ModelController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'toDoListService' defined in file [services/ToDoListService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'modelRepository' defined in com.example.todolist3.repositories.ModelRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.todolist3.models.Task
```

So probably class Task isn't recognized by spring boot conspect, but I've added it to @EntityScan and it still doesn't work. How could I repair it?

Comment: The fact that you have a meriad of annotations on your class seems to indicate you are doing things wrong. You should have your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in `com.example.todolist3` and ditch that `ProjectConfig` class. Everything else should be automatically detected. Depending on your Spring Boot version make sure you have the proper persistence library. You should just have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as a dependency if you have hibernate or `persistence-api` dependencies, remove them!. Unrlated, but hurts my eyes, the `@Repository` only adds clutter. Remove it.

Comment: And take the “.*” out of the “@ComponentScan” annotation